# Running time T(n) of algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I have analyzed running time of following alogirthm i analyzed theta but can its running time could be Big O?

```
                               Cost             Time
1.  for i ←1 to n                c1             n   
2.      do for j ← i to n        c2             n
3.          do k ← k+ j          c3             n-1
T(n) = c1n +c2n+c3(n-1)
     = C1n+C2n+C3(n-1)
     = n(C1+C2)+n-1
     = n+n-1
Or T(n) = Ө(n)
So running time is Ө(n)
```

Comment: I'm confused are these loops back to back? Shouldnt this be 0(n^2). can you explain what you are trying to compute for me, what the symbols mean. `i <- 1` `<-` means equals?

Comment: Your calculation is wrong. c3 is a simple sum, and thus a constant-time computation. Moreover, since the three statements are nested one inside the other, their costs must be multiplied, rather than added.
The total cost is T(n) = n * n * 1 = O(n^2)

Comment: but c3 is inside loop so how it would be constant or 1?

Answer (score 2):

```
1.  for i ←1 to n                c1             n   
2.      do for j ← i to n        c2             n
3.          do k ← k+ j          c3             1
```

`T(n) = n * n * 1 = O(n^2)` @Giulio Franco

It's a nested loop that does a constant time operation in there.

`do k ← k+ j` is constant because it's a fixed length of time for the operation to take place no matter what inputs you put. `k + j`

```
loop(n)
   loop(n)
       constant time(1)
```

When it's a loop inside a loop you multiply. `n*n*1`

```
loop(n)

loop(n)
```

These loops aren't nested.

this would be `n + n`

`O(n+n)` which reduces to `O(n)`

Answer (score 2):

Your loop will continue as follows (well-known arithmetic [progression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) formula):

[image]

-which also can be estimated as  [image] since big-O gives majority estimation.

Comment: That is not `n*n` for inner loop. That is sum of dependent from outer loop counts (first teta-expression shows that quite well, I think)